# What is the exact meaning of "dans le cadre de" and when should it be used?

Tags: sens, prépositions, locutions

I keep hearing that phrase almost daily without exactly knowing what it means, but only a guess I have made up from the context of the conversation.

What does it exactly mean, and when/where do I use it (without mistakes) myself?

Comment: It could mean a lot of things and more context is needed to help you. Are you sure you don't mean "dans **le** cadre".

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It seemed an error to me at first glance, but the article I got it from is a government press and contains no errors.

Comment: Is there a context in which "la" could also be correct? I read that from an official gov statement from the French speaking part of Suisse and I don't know if it is correct or not

Comment: It is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be "dans **le** cadre".
It means "in the context" or "as part of".

"Dans le cadre des opérations" => "In the context of operations"

http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/dans+le+cadre+de.html

Answer (score 2):

**Cadre** might be feminine nowadays when referring to a female manager/officer/executive (e.g. *[une cadre supérieure](https://www.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ressources/bibliotheque/dictionnaires/terminologie_relations_professionnelles/cadre_superieur.html)*) but preceded by *dans*, it is an obvious grammar mistake (See [TLFi B.-3.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cadre)), *cadre* means "frame" here and *dans le cadre*, "within the limits/context".

Surprisingly, it is not that rare and I found it in a official French writing:

> [Avis relatif à l'extension d'un accord conclu **dans la cadre** de la convention collective nationale des bureaux d'études techniques, cabinets d'ingénieurs-conseils, sociétés de conseils](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexteArticle.do;jsessionid=00782A2830D38F69979F836AD17A2B0E.tpdila21v_1?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000027665821&idArticle=JORFARTI000027665822&dateTexte=20130706&categorieLien=cid)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Can you throw me an example on how to form it in grammatical manner? As in `"dans la" + "cadre" + "de" + "noun"` Is that right?

Comment: To stay grammatical, that **must** be *dans **le** cadre de la convention collective*. The quoted text is blatantly incorrect.

Comment: Yeah, but I meant, if in the future I need to use it in my own sentences, which rules should I follow to construct a statement with it

Comment: What kind of rule are you thinking of?

Comment: I mean, it I wanted to use the phrase in my own sentences, what are the valid ways to use it, just like there are formulas for constructing a present tense, paste tense ... so on

Comment: There is no particular "formula", *cadre* is a masculine word and is always singular in the set expression ***dans le cadre** du/de la/des*.

Answer (score 1):

It means : **in the context of/as part of/within the scope of**.
For example :

> Dans le cadre de notre projet d'implantation en Chine, nous avons décidé d'accélérer la production des modèles X

could be translated

> In the context of our Chinese expansion project, we decided to accelerate the production of X models

Comment: It does not mean "in the context of" independently of the context. What about "dans le cadre de votre contrat..." (**within the scope** of your policy), "dans le cadre (juridique)", (**within a (legal) framework**), "j'ai traité ce sujet dans le cadre de ma recherche" (I looked into this topic **as part of my research**), "ce personnage ne rentre pas dans le cadre" (this character is outside **the frame** of the picture), et je dosi en oublier...

Comment: What do you mean by independently of the context ?

Comment: It means that saying "[dans le cadre de] means "in the context of" "  is not correct in every context.  OP having given no context, "dans le cadre de"  would be translated differently in other contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is very close to the word *frame* in English, and its usages as in: *the legislators who frame the regulations*, *to frame a proposal*, *frame of reference*, and just the meaning of *structure*: *an appropriate frame through which to explore dramatic situations*.